# GoogleSpreadsheet, VLOOKUP with an empty cell

Tags: google-sheets, gs-vlookup

I have this matrix for key/values

```
1 | one
2 | two
3 | three
  | none
```

and the *VLOOKUP* cell

```
=VLOOKUP(A10,A1:B4,2,false)
```

If the cell `A10` contains any number from 1 to 3 it is ok, but if the cell `A10` is empty the *VLOOKUP* returns: *"#N/A"* -> _"Error: Did not find value '' in *VLOOKUP* evaluation."_

Any possibility to make *VLOOKUP* to work also with empty cells?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found a solution [here](http://www.free-training-tutorial.com/shortsum/vlookup-isnaShortsum.html):

```
=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A10,A1:B4,2,false)), B4, VLOOKUP(A10,A1:B4,2,false))
```

Check that `B4` is the hardcoded position of the *"none"* text so this is extracted not using the *VLOOKUP* it self.

I really hope someone comes with something less ugly ;)