# Google spreadsheet -- how do I sum up my wages in this spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to calculate my earnings on a Google Spreadsheet but have no idea what I am doing. I got this far with spreadsheets, but VLOOKUP returns a #N/A error and I can't calculate the sum in column B5. What am I doing wrong? Here's my spreadsheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bsbQ4_0cITvdTqWWdX-Et1fiTL9Qw3WD_aminlpqgwY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: #N/A is simply because you haven't entered any data yet. But, if you'd like to get rid of that you could have a look at [GoogleSpreadsheet, VLOOKUP with an empty cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28107279/googlespreadsheet-vlookup-with-an-empty-cell) or [Suppress #N/A returned by Google Sheets vlookup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37865095/suppress-n-a-returned-by-google-sheets-vlookup), or Google the same issue. FWIW, as an accountant, I'd make your "Total" sheet show the monthly values of both Time and Value, also easier to edit the formulae.

Answer (score 0):

The error message `#N/A` is caused by the `VLOOKUP` operation in cell D9.  It is looking up cell C9, which is blank.  There must be a value in a `VLOOKUP` operation.  If you want to make this message go away, either put a value into C9 or use the `IFERROR` function. This only gives a value if the output is not an error.  In cell D9, you can put this formula: 
`=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(C9,$C$2:$D$5,2,FALSE))`.  This should return nothing if there is an error.